# Fetch the nested Json value with Url

Tags: json, angular

Am using angular2. I have a nested Json like :

```js
[
  {
    "Name": "aa",
    "vallue": 11,
    "type": [
      {
        "test1": "value1",
        "test2": "value2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "bb",
    "vallue": 22,
    "type": [
      {
        "test1": "value1",
        "test2": "value2",
      }
    ]
  }
    .....]
```

I have to access this Json data based on the Name. The name is retrieved successfully from the URL , like

```js
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
          this.name= params['id'];
```

and in the constructor of my component get data from url

```js
constructor(private http : Http ,private route: ActivatedRoute){
      this.http.get('http://192.168.0.101:8000/json1')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(data =>{ this.result = data});
        
    }
```

I want to display the table which contains

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" width="500">
    <tr><th>NAME</th><th>Type</th><th>prefix</th><th>rate</th></tr>
    <tr *ngFor = "let d of result['{{name}}']">
        <td>{{name}}</td><td>{{d.test1}}</td><td>{{d.test2}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

how can I display the specific details..Is there any possible solution .??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let item of result">
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td><td>{{item.type[0].test1}}</td><td>{{item.type[0].test2}}</td>
</tr>
```

you can iterate over the 'result' property, then print for each entry the .Name, and then the .test1 and .test2 from .type[0] (because type property is an array).

UPDATE: if you want to show only some elements in the template, one option is to filter the array in the component (in the example, return only the those white Name equals 'aa').

```
this.result = data.filter( item => item.Name === 'aa')
```

Comment: thanks@Christian . But I didn't want to display all the json data. If the parameter is " aa " , then display the "test1" and "test2" data of "aa"... Is there any possible solution ..?

Comment: The best way is to do this is in the component and not in the template. In the component you can filter the array and in the template, show it. I'll update the answer. Or you can use a custom pipe.